# libffi segmentation fault with void function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ffi, libffi

I can't determine the cause of crash of this code:

```
#define MACOSX
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ffi/ffi.h>

void sum(int64_t *a, int64_t *b, int64_t *c) {
      *c = *a + *b;
}

int main() {
      int64_t ai = 1, bi = 2, ci;

      ffi_cif cif;
      ffi_status status;
      ffi_type *arg_types[] = {
            &ffi_type_pointer,
            &ffi_type_pointer,
            &ffi_type_pointer,
      };
      void *args[] = {&ai, &bi, &ci};

      status = ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, 3, &ffi_type_void, arg_types);
      assert(status == FFI_OK);

      ffi_call(&cif, FFI_FN(sum), NULL, args);

      printf("%lld\n", ci);

      return 0;
}
```

It fails with segmentation fault error. As I know `ffi_call` must ignore return value pointer if `ffi_prep_cif` is called with `ffi_type_void`.

**UPDATE**

`lldb` output:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000dd4 a.out`sum(a=0x0000000000000001, b=0x0000000000000002, c=0x00007fff5fbffac0) at main2.c:8
   5    #include <ffi/ffi.h>
   6    
   7    void sum(int64_t *a, int64_t *b, int64_t *c) {
-> 8          *c = *a + *b;
   9    }
   10   
   11   int main() {
```

So, it crashes inside the void function (attempting to dereference `a`?, `*` before `a` was underlined).

Comment: *Where* does it fail?  A debugger can tell you this.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I added trace in update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with level of indirection.  Your CIF is correct for the function presented, but the actual arguments you send to it (the elements of array `args`) are not.

The elements of the argument array should be *pointers to* the argument values.  When the function parameters are of pointer type, that means you must pass pointers to appropriate pointer values.  Instead, you attempt to pass the actual values directly.  As a result, the function implementation attempts to dereference the integer value of `a` (1) as if it were a pointer value.

For a function with the signature and CIF you present, an FFI call to it might look like this:

```
  int64_t ai = 1, bi = 2, ci;
  int64_t *ap = &ai, *bp = &bi, *cp = &ci;
  void *args[] = {&ap, &bp, &cp};  // <-- pointers to the (pointer) arguments

  // ...

  ffi_call(&cif, FFI_FN(sum), NULL, args);
```